# Get data vector from stairstep plot Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How can one get the data vectors from the output of the stairs function in Matlab? I tried the following

```
h = stairs(x,y);
```

[image]

Then I get the data from the handle:

```
x = h.XData; 
y = h.YData;
```

but when x and y are plotted, they look as a piece-wise function, not the stairs.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: when you run `h.Xdata` and `h.Ydata`, you get what you passed into the plot function. stairs function does more process on the input data to make plot look like strairs

Comment: Did you produce the second figure with `plot`? If you do that the result will naturally be different from `stairs`. In signal processing terms, `stairs` does a zero-order hold (horizontal lines), whereas `plot` does first-order hold (join consecutive data points with straight lines)

Comment: Yes, I used plot ... but I want to get the data vector really

Comment: The data vector is what you are already doing: `x = h.XData; y = h.YData;`. That's it. If you plot that data with `stairs` again you'll get the same result

Comment: Understood. But the actual stairs vector is needed in order to pass it through fill...

Comment: The actual stairs vectors are `x = h.XData; y = h.YData`. I don't understand what else you want

Comment: given the original function x = [1 2 3 4 ...] and y = [.1 .2 .15  .25] the stairs function would be something like xs = [0.5 1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5 3.5 3.5 4.5 4.5] and ys = [.1 .1 .2 .2 .15 .15 .25 .25]....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data necessary to display a `stairs` plot are relatively easy to generate by yourself.

Assuming you have `x` and `y`. To generate 2 vectors `xs` and `ys` such as `plot(xs,ys)` will display the same thing than `stairs(x,y)`, you can use the following 2 steps method:

- replicate each element of `x` and `y`
- offset the new vectors by one element (remove the first point of one vector and the last point of the other)

Example with code:

```
%% demo data
x = (0:20).';
y = [(0:10),(9:-1:0)].' ;

hs = stairs(x,y) ;
hold on

%% generate `xs` and `ys`
% replicate each element of `x` and `y` vector
xs = reshape([x(:) x(:)].',[],1) ;
ys = reshape([y(:) y(:)].',[],1) ;

% offset the 2 vectors by one element
%  => remove first `xs` and last `ys`
xs(1)   = [] ;
ys(end) = [] ;

% you're good to go, this will plot the same thing than stairs(x,y)
hp = plot(xs,ys) ;

% and they will also work with the `fill` function
hf = fill(xs,ys,'g') ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Matlab documentation explicit says:

> [xb,yb] = stairs(___) does not create a plot, but returns matrices xb
> and yb of the same size, such that plot(xb,yb) plots the stairstep
> graph.